# Restart ruby program

Tags: ruby

I am writing an IRC bot and my intention is to have "!reboot" reboot the bot. I have already got it to part from a channel and break the running loop, but I cannot get it to re-run the file.

It needs to start a new process and load up a new version of the file, so that any new commands etc. and configuration changes can be loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run [`Kernel.exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005968) function that will replace running process with the new one.

The advantage of `exec` function is that there's no time span when two different bots are run simultaneously.  It was one process and  after `exec` call it's instantly replaced with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You could rerun the bot by using a system command `system("ruby /path/to/my/bot.rb")` when a restart is required.

It is not something I would do without a very good reason. It seems a nicer solution to build the bot in such a way that it is able to just reload new commands and configuration changes at any time, so a restart is not required at all.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities, one simple, one probably less so.

First, could you put the irb execution into a looping command/shell script file? Then your reboot becomes a simple `exit` and the script jumps back and runs your Ruby file again. If a different file is to be used, the name (or path) could be put into an environment variable before exit.

As an alternative, could you call `eval` with your rewritten script as argument? It's one of the techniques used in Giles Bowkett's [Archaeopteryx](http://wiki.github.com/gilesbowkett/archaeopteryx) - change the code and save it, then (in this instance) a timed loop picks up the new code and runs it using `eval`.